# Nice looking window - like Spotify

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to create a window similar to Spotify, there is no border or title bar and the corners are rounded.

I tried with using a transparent color, set it to 255,0,255 (pink) and tried to create rounded corners but it leaves a pink edge there.

So I need to:

- remove the title bar and border
- give the app rounded corners

Any help on the above 2 issues is much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "create a window"? Did you mean this [Spotify](http://www.spotify.com/int/)? Do you want help with CSS? What have you already tried?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa984300(v=vs.71).aspx

Comment: @Zasz: Hi, not CSS, it's for a windows application not a website.

Comment: Use WPF and Expression Blend to create exactly whatever kind of window you want : http://windowsclient.net/learn/videos_wpf.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the title bar and border, you can set your form's `FormBorderStyle` to `None`. As for the rounded corners, you can use regions or the `TransparencyKey` property (which you mentioned using - it won't work if your form is double-buffered, in case that's your issue) but those result in aliased edges. (I can't download Spotify so I don't know if it has that issue.) I believe it's common (for effects like shadows) to take a screenshot (using `Graphics.CopyFromScreen`) of the screen behind the form and draw on that.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: Oh, and I made something that does apply here. It's at http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?t=618118. The forms do have rounded corners and move/resize using `WndProc`. I'm also getting an example ready.

Comment: @MerlynMorgan-Graham: Oops :P Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I do think you have to deal with ["Regions"](http://www.vcskicks.com/custom_shape_form_region.php) to achieve this effect. Also the article points to an alternative method to get the effect with the help of [transparency](http://www.vcskicks.com/custom_shape_form_transperancy.php).